# Azure: How long for DNS of my deploy to go live?

Tags: azure

So my production deploy is live, and has been for 10+ minutes.

I can hit the code via the IP on the production instance.

But when I hit the DNS name  (mything.cloudapp.net), it ain't there yet. The DNS just isn't up.

How long does it take for DNS to go live?

Thanks!

Comment: It often depends, here is a link http://www.technologytricks.com/speed-up-dns-propagation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cloudapp.net has a TTL of 3600, so it will take up to one hour to go live assuming that Azure informs its DNS server immediately (which you can verify by querying their ns1.azure.net directly).  If users do not have an old value cached or a failure cached then it could be immediate.

However if your deployment already existed and you are VIP swapping in an update then your IP address will not change and thus neither will your DNS record.  In this case you should be working immediately.

Comment: This is my experience. I have seen it take an hour on two diff occassions. I believe (but am not certain) this is the case even when the ip addy stays the same.

Comment: AFAIK, the whole point of the VIP swap is so that cached DNS entries can continue to work without interruption.  Certainly works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you been deploying directly from within Visual Studio? In my experience (though I've not checked lately), this causes the existing deployment to be recreated and the IP address to change.

However, if you use Visual Studio to package the solution, then use the Management Portal to upllad and upgrade the deployment, it doesn't (and it's quicker).

Comment: Yes, I do deploy from within VS.  I had the odd situation of successful deploy from VS, then azure shut my account down (it was a trial), then I had to redeploy from VS.  I really like the VS deploy because it is "one click and forget" I only have the issue with long DNS outage after Azure shut down my instance (to avoid charges during the trial). If the instance is running, it stays running...

Comment: The latest version of the VS tools includes an option under Advanced Settings: Enable deployment upgrade.  If you have this checked then it won't delete the instance, just upgrade it so you shouldn't get a new IP address.